# C++ 11 - Modifying members of a struct in a vector of structs

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, embedded, unique-ptr

I've searched elsewhere and here on SO for ways to do this, but didn't find any answers that addressed my issues and concerns.

**Constraints:**

1. I'm using **C++ 11** on an **embedded** device.
2. I can't use **`std::string`**
3. I can't use **`std::make_unique()`** (but I can use `std::unique_ptr` with `new`)
4. I can't use **`strcpy_s()`**

**Problems I'm having**

The primary problem I'm having is that in the `AvailableZones::upsertZone` method I'd like to add a Zone to the vector if it doesn't already exist (using the name argument as a "key"). If it exists, I'd like to update the temperature and humidity members of the zone. The "adding" part works, however, the updating part does not.

The next issue I have is in the `AvailableZones::findZone` member. I'd like to be able to return a Zone such that the caller is not responsible for freeing/deleting the returned value.

**Concerns:**

Being new to C++, I'm pretty sure I'm not doing a lot of things the correct C++11 way. I'm open (eager actually) to any/all guidance.
In the `AvailableZones::findZone` method I'd like return `Zone` I have rather than create a copy or use `new`/`malloc`. It looks like I'll need to use the regular `for`/`while` loop? I've seen some iterator code but it looks way to confusing/complicated but I'm not sure if using an iterator will solve this either.

**Best Practice related questions:**

1. In the `Zone` struct's destructor, if I use `delete`, it causes and
   exception when I run the code. I'm obviously doing something wrong.
2. In the `Zone` struct, can I make the `name` member a `std::unique_ptr`? If
   so, How? I've tried numerous ways but I'm not able to either get it
   to compile or work.
3. Is there is better way to implement the `Zone` constructor?

**The Code**

I've put comments in code to explain the intent of the method as well as where I need help.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Zone {
    Zone() {}
    Zone(const char* name, const float temperature, const float humidity)
    {
        auto bufferSize = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s", name);
        this->name = new char[bufferSize + 1];
        strcpy(this->name, name);
        this->temperature = temperature;
        this->humidity = humidity;
    }

    ~Zone() {
        // deleting name here causes an Exception
        //delete [] name;
    }

    char* name = nullptr;
    float temperature = 0.0f;
    float humidity = 0.0f;
};

class AvailableZones {
public:
    AvailableZones::AvailableZones() {
        m_zoneVec = std::vector<Zone>();
    }

    ~AvailableZones() {
    }

    /*
        Using Arguments, add a Zone to the private zoneVec member is it does not exist
        If is does exist (names of zones are unique and used as the "key"), then update
        the temperature and humidity of the existing zone with those in the arguments
    */
    void AvailableZones::upsertZone(const char *name, const float temperature, const float humidity) {

        for (auto zone : m_zoneVec) {
            if (strcmp(zone.name, name) == 0) {
                zone.temperature = temperature;
                zone.humidity = humidity;
                return;
            }
        }

        m_zoneVec.push_back(Zone(name, temperature, humidity));
    }

    /*
        Given a Zone name, find the zone and return it
        If a Zone with the given name does not exist
        return a nullptr
    */
    const Zone *AvailableZones::findZone(const char *name) const {

        for (auto zone : m_zoneVec) {
            if (strcmp(zone.name, name) == 0) {
                // I know this is not correct.
                // How would I do this, without using "new" and thus
                // forcing the caller to be responsible for deleting?
                return &zone;
            }
        }

        return nullptr;
    }

private:
    std::vector<Zone> m_zoneVec;
};


int main()
{
    auto livingRoom = "Living Room";
    AvailableZones availableZones;
    availableZones.upsertZone("Master Bedroom", 72.0f, 50.0f);
    availableZones.upsertZone(livingRoom, 70.0f, 48.0f);
    availableZones.upsertZone("Study", 68.0f, 46.0f);

    auto foundZone = availableZones.findZone(livingRoom);
    cout << foundZone->name << endl;
    cout << foundZone->temperature << endl;
    cout << foundZone->humidity << endl;

    assert(strcmp(livingRoom, foundZone->name) == 0);
    assert(70.0f == foundZone->temperature);
    assert(48.0f == foundZone->humidity);

    availableZones.upsertZone(livingRoom, 74.0f, 52.0f);

    foundZone = availableZones.findZone(livingRoom);

    assert(strcmp(livingRoom, foundZone->name) == 0);
    assert(74.0f == foundZone->temperature);
    assert(52.0f == foundZone->humidity);

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
The code below implements suggestions made by @max66 as well as @ Vaughn Cato and @Artemy Vysotsky. This code is now working as per my requirements. The following changes have been made:

1. Range based for loops are using references (or const references as
   the case may be). By default range based loops provide elements by
   value (this was also suggested by  @Vaughn Cato)
2. In the `upsertZone` method, I'm using `emplace_back()` so that the Zone instance is created in-place at the location provided by the container. With `push_back()` (earlier code) a temporary copy was being created, only to be thrown away (I'm assuming because I didn't have a move constructor implemented).
3. Using strlen (as suggested by @ArtemyVysotsky) as against snprintf, allowed me to use an initializer-list in the `Zone` constructor.
4. Implemented Copy assignment operator `Zone &operator=(Zone &other)`
5. Implemented copy constructor
6. Implemented Move assignment operator `Zone &operator=(Zone &&other)`
7. Implemented Move constructor

**Findings:**
Each time I add an element to the vector. Previous elements are "copied" to the new container location and earlier elements are destructed. I was hoping that they'd be moved rather than copied. I'm not sure if there is something I need to do to ensure they are moved instead of copied.

**Furher Update**
It looks like, in order for the Move constructor to be used it needs to be `noexcept`. Once I did this, the same code without any changes now uses the Move instead of Copy.

**Working code as per suggestions made**

```
struct Zone {
    Zone() {}
    Zone(const char* name, const float zoneTemperature, const float zoneHumidity)
        :name(strcpy(new char[strlen(name) + 1], name))
        ,temperature{ zoneTemperature }
        ,humidity {zoneHumidity}
    {
        cout << "Zone constructor: " << name << endl;
    }
    /* Copy Constructor */
    Zone(Zone const& other)
        :name(strcpy(new char[strlen(other.name) + 1], other.name))
        ,temperature{ other.temperature }
        ,humidity{ other.humidity }
    {
        std::cout << "In Zone Copy Constructor. name = " << other.name << ". Copying resource." << std::endl;
    }
    /* Move Constructor */
    Zone(Zone&& other) noexcept
        : name(nullptr)
        , temperature(0.0f)
        , humidity(0.0f)
    {
        std::cout << "In Zone Move Constructor. name = "    << other.name << ". Moving resource." << std::endl;

        // Copy the data pointer and its length from the   
        // source object.  
        name = other.name;
        temperature = other.temperature;
        humidity = other.humidity;

        // Release the data pointer from the source object so that  
        // the destructor does not free the memory multiple times.  
        other.name = nullptr;
        other.temperature = 0.0f;
        other.humidity = 0.0f;
    }

    ~Zone()
    {
        cout << "Zone Destructor: " << name << endl;
        delete[] name;
    }

    /* Copy Assignment Operator */
    Zone& operator=(Zone const& other) {
        std::cout << "In Zone Copy Assignment Operator. name = " << other.name << "." << std::endl;
        Zone tmpZone(other);
        std::swap(name, tmpZone.name);
        std::swap(temperature, tmpZone.temperature);
        std::swap(humidity, tmpZone.humidity);
        return *this;
    }

    /* Move Assignment Operator */
    Zone& operator=(Zone&& other) noexcept {
        std::cout << "In Zone Move Assignment Operator. name = " << other.name << "." << std::endl;

        if (this != &other)
        {
            // Free the existing resource.  
            delete[] name;

            // Copy the data pointer and its length from the   
            // source object.  
            name = other.name;
            temperature = other.temperature;
            humidity = other.humidity;

            // Release the data pointer from the source object so that  
            // the destructor does not free the memory multiple times.  
            other.name = nullptr;
            other.temperature = 0.0f;
            other.humidity = 0.0f;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    char* name = nullptr;
    float temperature = 0.0f;
    float humidity = 0.0f;
};

class AvailableZones {
public:
    AvailableZones::AvailableZones() {
        m_zoneVec = std::vector<Zone>();
    }

    ~AvailableZones() {
    }

    /*
        Using Arguments, add a Zone to the private zoneVec member is it does not exist
        If is does exist (names of zones are unique and used as the "key"), then update
        the temperature and humidity of the existing zone with those in the arguments
    */
    void AvailableZones::upsertZone(const char *name, const float temperature, const float humidity) {

        for (auto &zone : m_zoneVec) {
            if (strcmp(zone.name, name) == 0) {
                zone.temperature = temperature;
                zone.humidity = humidity;
                return;
            }
        }       

        m_zoneVec.emplace_back(name, temperature, humidity);
    }

    /*
        Given a Zone name, find the zone and return it
        If a Zone with the given name does not exist
        return a nullptr
    */
    const Zone *AvailableZones::findZone(const char *name) const {

        for (auto const &zone : m_zoneVec) {
            if (strcmp(zone.name, name) == 0) {
                return &zone;
            }
        }

        return nullptr;
    }

private:
    std::vector<Zone> m_zoneVec;
};

void doWork() {
    static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<Zone>::value, "Zone should be noexcept MoveConstructible");
    auto livingRoom = "Living Room";
    AvailableZones availableZones;
    availableZones.upsertZone("Master Bedroom", 72.0f, 50.0f);
    availableZones.upsertZone(livingRoom, 70.0f, 48.0f);
    availableZones.upsertZone("Study", 68.0f, 46.0f);

    auto foundZone = availableZones.findZone(livingRoom);
    cout << foundZone->name << endl;
    cout << foundZone->temperature << endl;
    cout << foundZone->humidity << endl;

    assert(strcmp(livingRoom, foundZone->name) == 0);
    assert(70.0f == foundZone->temperature);
    assert(48.0f == foundZone->humidity);

    availableZones.upsertZone(livingRoom, 74.0f, 52.0f);

    foundZone = availableZones.findZone(livingRoom);
    assert(strcmp(livingRoom, foundZone->name) == 0);
    assert(74.0f == foundZone->temperature);
    assert(52.0f == foundZone->humidity);

    foundZone = availableZones.findZone("Non Existent Zone");
    assert(foundZone == nullptr);
}


int main()
{
    doWork();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you are using C++11, why do you use `malloc`?

Comment: I've gone through many iterations, I guess that's just some left over experiements :). Updated the code to remove use of malloc

Comment: Change `for (auto zone : m_zoneVec)` to `for (auto& zone : m_zoneVec)`

Comment: why are you using snprintf in place of straightforward strlen?

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky, I didn't realize I could/should use `strlen` for a `char*`. Examples I had seen used a `char[]` (with a known length). I've changed that to use `strlen` now. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no use (and is dangerous) in returning a `nullptr` from `findZone()` if you don't check if the pointer returned is `nullptr` or not

```
auto foundZone = availableZones.findZone(livingRoom);
cout << foundZone->name << endl;
```

There is a lot of different ways to solve your problem with `findZone()`; to avoid problems, I suggest to avoid pointers and return a copy of the element (but you have to write a copy constructor); but, if you really want return a pointer, you can rewrite the function as follows

```
Zone const * findZone(const char *name) const {
    for ( auto const & zone : m_zoneVec) {
        if (strcmp(zone.name, name) == 0) {
            return & zone;
        }
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

The point is use a `const` (because the method is `const`) **reference** to the element in `m_zoneVec` (`auto const & zone : m_zoneVec`; observe the `&`) when now your using a **temporary** **copy** (`auto zone : m_zoneVec`; no `&` so copy and not reference). So you can return the pointer of the element of the vector instead of the pointer of a temporary object that is immediately destroyed.

You have exactly the same problem in `upsertZone()`: you loop testing and (in case) modifying a **copy** of the element in the vector

```
    for (auto zone : m_zoneVec) {  // DANGER: zone is a **copy**
        if (strcmp(zone.name, name) == 0) {
            zone.temperature = temperature;
            zone.humidity = humidity;
            return;
        }
    }
```

So you modify the copy that is immediately destroyed; the original `Zone` is untouched.

You have to modify the **reference**

```
    for (auto & zone : m_zoneVec) {  // with & zone is a **reference**
        if (strcmp(zone.name, name) == 0) {
            zone.temperature = temperature;
            zone.humidity = humidity;
            return;
        }
    }
```

But, very very important, you should create a copy constructor (and, maybe, a move constructor); a copy constructor that allocate (with `new`) a new array for name; otherwise there is the default copy constructor that copy the pointer.

So, by example, when you write

```
m_zoneVec.push_back(Zone(name, temperature, humidity));
```

you create a temporary object, you push it in the vector through the creation of a copy and the destruction of the temporary. If `delete`, in the `Zone` destructor is enabled, the destruction of the temporary `delete` the `name` and the value in the vector is using a `name` that point to a free zone. From this point, the behaviour of the program is undefined and, anyway, when `availableZone` is destroyed (at the end of the program), `delete` is called over a pointer that is been deleted before --> crash!

You can avoid the copy in insertion using `emplace_back()` (and I suggest this)

```
m_zoneVec.emplace_back(name, temperature, humidity);
```

but adding more elements in `m_zoneVec` you can cause a relocation of the vector, so move copies and destruction.

If you can use `std::unique_ptr`, I suppose you can use `std::shared_ptr` also.

A possible alternative to an explicit copy and move constructor creation is the use of a `name` inserted in a smart pointer (unique or shared, according to the use of `AvailableZones`.

Comment: Small comment to storing name as smart-pointer - since it is allocated with new[] custom deleter will be required so delete[] will be called and not delete.

Comment: @max66, Lots of good suggestions, explanations and examples! Thank you. I'll be implementing what you've suggested and will post the code here once done. the `delete name` in the destructor no longer throws an exception. However, I still fell like there is a memory leak (the Zone names). But let me post my code, once I'm done.

Comment: @max66, yes the multiple deletes (due to what you explained in your answer) were the reasons for the exception. Thank you. Also, now that I understand better what's going on (thanks to your great explanation), the memory leaks comment I made earlier is not valid.